# Resource management by Linux

Tags: linux

When a program with some theards, mutexes, shared data, file handles crash because of too much memory allocation, which all resources are freed. How do you recover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean, how do you go back and free up the resources that were allocated by the now-crashed process, well, you don't have to.

When the process exit(2)'s or dies by a signal all of the OS-allocated resources will be retrieved. This is the kernel's job.

Comment: But the process is not doing a clean exit- isnt that why the os did not release it in the first place?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the exit occurs as a result of a system call or a signal, it will execute the same kernel code and do the same cleanup. That's the kernel's job and if it doesn't happen it's called a leak, it's about as serious as a kernel bug can be, and it's cause to withdraw a release, post security alerts, and generally launch into all kinds of emergency update hysteria.

Answer (score 1):

You recover by checking the results of resource acquisition functions and not allowing unchecked errors to occur in the first place.

Comment: In the real world though, bugs happen.

Comment: Try/catch on memory allocation can help you safely shut down though.

Unless OOM killer gets you first.

Comment: malloc never fails on Linux. Linux just kills the app when it tries to use the nonexistent memory. A try/catch will not help with this.

Answer (score 1):

All resources that belongs to the process are cleaned up.

The only exceptions would be the [sysv](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node21.html) shared memory/message queues/semaphores - which although might have been created by the process are not owned by it.